# How can I convert a String in 2 differents values for 2 differents int

Tags: java, string, int

I'm new here and idk how this page works, my problem I think is simple, I'm studying java on my own but I don't have answer for this and I think someone from here can help me.
The thing is I want to put to the int A the value of 12 of the string z and 4 to the int B. What can I do?
Thanks for ur time

```java
String z = "12 4"
int A;
int B;
```

Comment: pls show us some of the code which you have written ?

Comment: This feels a lot like you are asking others to do your homework.

Read the javadoc for String::split, String::substring, String::indexOf and Integer::parseInt.

There are a number of ways to do this simple operation and the methods above should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split string first by space character  and parse them to integer:

```java
String[] parts = z.split(" "); // Return an array of string
int A = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); // 12
int B = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); // 4
```

Or you can use whitespace regex to split string following:

```java
String[] parts = z.split("\\s+");
```

Note: you should handle your parsing functions in `try catch` block, to avoid error string not in number format:

```java
try {
    String[] parts = z.split(" "); // Return an array of string
    int A = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); // 12
    int B = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); // 4
} catch (e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class brainchild{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String z = "12 4";
    String [] str = z.split(" ");
    int A = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    int B = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
    System.out.println(A);
    System.out.println(B);
    }
```

}

Here the idea is to split the string where space is found `String [] str = z.split(" ");`
and save it to an string array.
Then access the first element and convert it to integer type and assign it to the integer A `int A = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);` .Do similarly with B.

Answer (score -1):

Save this code as Main.java and run it.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String z = "12 4" ;
        int A;
        int B; 
        String[] arr = z.split(" ") ; //splits the String wherever it finds spaces
        A = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]); 
        B = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); 
        System.out.println(A);
        System.out.println(B);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question.